# Python - как рассчитать вероятность для t-распределения Стьюдента

Tags: python

Всем привет!

В экселе есть функция `=СТЬЮДРАСП (`или `=TDIST` в английском варианте), которая в моем случае дает результат: `=СТЬЮДРАСП(300;2;1) = 5.55е-6`.

В Питоне мне удалось найти такой вариант:

```
from scipy.stats import t
a=t.pdf(300,2,1)
print(a)
```

результат `3.740e-08`.

Может что неверно выбрал? :)

Answer (score 5):

```
from scipy.stats import t

a = t.sf(300, 2)
print(a)

# Напечатает: 5.55546296468e-06
```

Comment: Александр, снимаю шляпу :)

Comment: @leonardik, если ответ помог, то вы можете кликнуть слева от него по галочке и треугольничку вверх :)

Comment: ради интереса, просто подобрал подходящую или в буржуйской терминологии матстата разобрался?